# how to fix this h1 line

Tags: html, css

I have this code but don't know why when I put  on top (still in div) and the code didn't work, but when I put  at the bottom, it works. Can you explain it to me?

```css
.pseudo6 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.pseudo6 p:first-child i {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo6">
  <h1>Match all 'i' elements in all first child 'p' elements</h1>
  <p>I am a <i>strong</i> person. I am a <i>strong</i> person.</p>
  <p>I am a <i>strong</i> person. I am a <i>strong</i> person.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> For :first-child to work in IE8 and earlier, a DOCTYPE must be declared.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because `p:first-child` means that it's applied only to the `p` tag when it's a first child. Try to use `p:first-of-type` it must help.

Answer (score 1):

By the way Oleksandr Kovpashko shows, try this css:

```
.pseudo6 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.pseudo6 p:first-of-type i {
  color: blue;
}
```